# Independent set problem for graphs with very large independent sets

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Is there a number $\alpha < 1$ such that the independent set problem is polynomial for input graphs whose independence number is at least $\alpha n$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices)?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Do you want to find a maximal IS or one of size at least $\alpha n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such $\alpha$ unless $\mathsf{P}= \mathsf{NP}$. Assuming such an $\alpha$ exists, you could solve the problem Independent Set for any graph in polynomial time.

Indeed, suppose $G = (V, E)$ a graph and $n = |V|$ ($V = \{1, 2, …, n\}$). Consider $N = \left\lceil \frac{n}{1-\alpha}\right\rceil$, $K = N - n$ and $G' = (V', E')$ with:

- $V' = V\cup \{n+1, n+2, …, n + K\}$;
- $E' = E$.

Meaning you add a certain number of isolated vertices. It is clear that the independence number of $G'$ is the independence number of $G$ plus $K$. However, $K = N - n \geqslant N - (1-\alpha)n = \alpha N = \alpha |V'|$. Given that the size of $G'$ is polynomial in the size of $G$, if you can compute the independence number of $G'$ in polynomial time, you can do it for $G$.